# Query to Display Polygons not Working on Geodjango-Leaftlet Web App

Tags: postgis, leaflet, geojson, geodjango, django

I am currently working on a Geodjango-Leaflet-OpenStreetMap web app. I have around 540000 polygons of property boundaries that were drawn in ArcMap; the polygons will be imported to the web app later through PostgreSQL+PostGIS. Recently, I have imported one polygon to the PG db.

There is a search bar on the web app. I want the user to enter a polygon's unique ID in the search bar, and the polygon to appear on the screen soon after.

However, after entering the polygon's ID at the home page, the site redirects me to the results page with no polygon.

How can I fix the code?

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <title>Home</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gis {width: 100%;height:1080px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" >  </script>
    
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function our_layers(map,options){
        var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'    
            
        });

    
        {% for i in object_list %}
        L.geoJSON({{ i | safe }}).addTo(map);       
        {% endfor %}

</script>

{{ geo_json }}

<form action="{% url 'results' %}" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</form>

{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView , ListView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Q
from app.models import test11


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class search(ListView):
    model = test11
    template_name = 'results.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = test11.objects.filter(
            Q(objectid__icontains=query) 
        )
        return object_list

def test11_datasets(request):
    test111 = serialize('geojson', test11.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(test111,content_type='json')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from app.views import HomePageView, test11_datasets, search 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name = 'home'),
    url(r'^test11_data/$', test11_datasets, name = 'test11'),  
    url(r'search_results/$', search.as_view(), name='results'),

]
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager


class test11(models.Model):
    objectid = models.BigIntegerField()
    shape_leng = models.FloatField()
    shape_area = models.FloatField()
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.objectid
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'test11'
```

Comment: Do you want to _fly to_ the Polygon corresponding to the ID? E.g. get centroid of Polygon from database and use this method: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-flyto